# In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class 'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider' not found error in laravel

Tags: laravel, roles, entrust

I try to build Administration Module with Role-based permissions using Entrust package.
then update composer.json file as follow:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.1",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"
},
```

after run `composer update` command 
After open up `config/app.php`, find the **providers array and add the entrust provider:**

```
Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,
```

Find the **aliases array and add the entrust facades:**

```
'Entrust'   => Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::class,
```

Run the command below from the command line to publish the package config file.

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Then get following error:

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider' not found

How to solve this error??
I also try `composer dump-autoload` command.But cannot solve this error.
then get following error.

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider' not found
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump
>   event returned with error code 1

please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create the ProdiverRepository yourself? Can you post the important lines of that class?

Comment: I firstly run php artisan make:auth command.I didn't create ProviderRepository myself.

Comment: Can you remove it from the composer.json and install it like I did it in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is inside the ProviderRepository, but my guess is that you have to import the class like this:

```
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;
```

If that does not work remove the package from your composer.json and install it like this:

```
composer require zizaco/entrust
```